# Does this sentence use nominative absolute phrase?

Tags: grammar, phrases

> A scientist, he always thinks about what is best for the people.

Is this "a scientist" part a nominative absolute phrase? It seems like nominative absolute phrase has to have a verb or adjective after the noun like this:

> The dragon slain, the knight could rest.

It is what makes me confused. I don't think the scientist sentence uses nominative absolute phrase since it only has a noun to describe "he". There is nothing more than a noun. So is it a nominative absolute phrase or not? If not, what's the name of that usage?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article (which I believe you quote from, and so ought to mention) 'A scientist,' is a shorter form of 'As he is a scientist,' and the necessary 'he' counts against this being a true nominative absolute. I'd still call it one; I'd reckon that some authority deems it sensible to broaden the definition to include such cases as they are basically so similar. [EnglishPlus](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000390.htm) gives 'The weather being rainy, we decided to postpone the trip.' which doesn't pass Wikipedia's test.

Comment: What do you mean by  "the necessary 'he' counts against this being a true nominative absolute"? Do you mean that if I include "he" in the phrase, it will not be a nominative absolute phrase but something else?

Comment: '_As_ the dragon _was_ slain, ...' Adding just a subordinator and a form of be converts the nominative absolute phrase into a subordinate clause, which satisfies the requirement in the Wikipedia article. But '_Since_ **he** _is_ a scientist, ...' requires the additional pronoun to recover the subordinate clause.

Comment: Hmm.... I can see the problem...

Comment: Does the same go with the sentences with adjectives? For example: Desperate to get to the car, he ran without an umbrella over his head.

Comment: I think your first example is ungrammatical. Or rather, it is two disconnected clauses, and a comma is inappropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article from 'The Garden of Phrases at [Grammar.ccc.com](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/phrases.htm) gives a good overview:

> ABSOLUTE PHRASE
>
> Usually (but not always, as we shall see), an absolute phrase (also
> called a nominative absolute) is a group of words consisting of a noun
> or pronoun and a participle as well as any related modifiers. Absolute
> phrases do not directly connect to or modify any specific word in the
> rest of the sentence; instead, they modify the entire sentence, adding
> information. They are always treated as parenthetical elements and are
> set off from the rest of the sentence with a comma or a pair of commas
> (sometimes by a dash or pair of dashes). Notice that absolute phrases
> contain a subject (which is often modified by a participle), but not a
> true finite verb.
>
> - *Their reputation as winners secured by victory, the New York Liberty
>   charged into the semifinals.*
> - *The season nearly finished, Rebecca Lobo and Sophie Witherspoon
>   emerged as true leaders.*
> - *The two superstars signed autographs into the night, their faces
>   beaming happily.*
>
> When the participle of an absolute phrase is a form of *to be*, such
> as *being* or *having been*, the participle is often left out but
> understood.
>
> - *The season [being] over, they were mobbed by fans in Times Square.*
> - *[Having been] Stars all their adult lives, they seemed used to the
>   attention.*
> - [*[Being] A scientist, he always thinks about what is best for the
>   people.*]
> - *The dragon [having been] slain, the knight could rest.*
>
> Another kind of absolute phrase is found after a modified noun; it
> adds a focusing detail or point of focus to the idea of the main
> clause. This kind of absolute phrase can take the form of a
> prepositional phrase, an adjective phrase, or a noun phrase.
>
> - *The old firefighter stood over the smoking ruins, his senses alert to
>   any sign of another flare-up.*
> - *His subordinates, their faces sweat-streaked and smudged with ash,
>   leaned heavily against the firetruck.*
> - *They knew all too well how all their hard work could be undone – in an
>   instant.*
>
> It is not unusual for the information supplied in the absolute phrase
> to be the most important element in the sentence. In fact, in
> descriptive prose, the telling details will often be wrapped into a
> sentence in the form of an absolute phrase:
>
> - *Coach Nykesha strolled onto the court, her arms akimbo and a large
>   silver whistle clenched between her teeth.*
> - *The new recruits stood in one corner of the gym, their uniforms stiff
>   and ill fitting, their faces betraying their anxiety.*
>
> A noun phrase can also exist as an absolute phrase:
>
> - *Your best friends, where are they now, when you need them?*
> - *And then there was my best friend Sally – the dear girl – who has
>   certainly fallen on hard times.*

I think it's best to disambiguate 'nominative absolute' and 'absolute construction' (I'd see the latter term as a hypernym). Constructions with free-standing adjectives/adjectivals:

- *Desperate to get to the car, he ran without an umbrella over his head.*
- *Exhausted, he gave up after 20 miles.*

are certainly recognised as 'absolute constructions' by many authorities.

Comment: Wow...this answers my question perfectly!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Very informative indeed!

Answer (score 0):

A scientist,

Gives information to the subject "he"

So I think it's not an absolute phrase but an appositive phrase since it does not add information to the entire sentence.

Comment: Don't you think "scientist" could explain the reason why "he always thinks about what is best for the people"? Can you explain in more details why you think it is an appositive phrase with a few more examples?